# rerun cron which was failed in the first attempt

Tags: php, cron

I have a folder where I have some files automatically created in some particular case.

I want to delete those files which are more than 10 days older.

I have a cron which does the job scheduled for every Sunday. I have set this up in the crontab.

I would like to know if there is any way I can have the cron rerun in case if the cron failed to delete the files on Sunday.

For example: if the job fails on Sunday, can we have it rerun after some time or the next day?

Comment: Why don't you just add another cron task to delete files older than 11 days on monday? So, if the first task fails or doesn't finish, the second one will do it.

Comment: thanks @ojovirtual. is that the only solution? just want to know if there are more ways to do the rerun.